Cup product structure on Galois cohomology
Let $G_S$ denote the Galois group of the maximal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ unramified outside a finite, non-empty set of primes, $S$. Let $p\in S$ and let $V, W$ be a pair of finite dimensional $p$-adic $G_S$-representations.
The cup product in Galois cohomology gives maps: $\bigcup_i: H^i(G_S, V)\otimes H^{2-i}(G_S, W)\longrightarrow H^2(G_S, V\otimes W)$. We may consider the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-subvector space of $H^2(G_S, V\otimes W)$ generated by the image of $\bigcup_i$, $i\le 2$. Denote this vector subspace by $H^2(G_S, V\otimes W)'$.
Are there any reasonable conditions on $V$ and $W$, under which $H^2(G_S, V\otimes W)' \cong H^2(G_S, V\otimes W)$?

Do you really want just bare isomorphism in your question, or equality?  (I don't know if there are finiteness results in place that guarantee that they are the same.) \ TeX note: $\bigcup$ \bigcup is for a sum-like operator, to be applied to a family of operands.  A binary cup product is usually denoted just by $\cup$ \cup.

@LSpice It is also usually denoted by $\smile$ \smile.

@LSpice all cohomology groups in my question are finite (see Ballaiche's survey on the BK conjecture, Proposition 2.1), so I expect the two notions to be the same. In essence I am asking about the surjectivity of the cup product map, or alternatively about the cohomology algebra to be generated in degree $\le 1$. I wonder if when $V$ and $W$ come from pure motives associated to curves this should be the case, but don't know of anything in the literature that should suggest this to be true.

@Z.M That is the smile-product. (In arithmetic, cup products in Galois cohomology are more frequently denoted by $\cup$ than $\smile$. I think.) Not that it matters, for once there is no danger of confusion.

Is that like a simile-product? No, don't answer that. I'll get my coat.

@ChrisWuthrich Sorry, what is the smile product that you are referring to? I did not find it in Google.

Neither me not Dave where serious. Sorry if my joke confused you. $\ddot{\smile}$
